# problemas con syntax de sqlite

Tags: mysql, sqlite

hola a todos tengo una pregunta sobre la syntax de sqlite, por lo que estoy enterado trabaja similar al de mysql, pero cuando trato de modificar dos tablas en sqlite me da error en la coma donde se encuentras 'users', 'score' para modificar  las dos tablas y mysql trabaja normal con  esta  syntax, que es lo que estoy haciendo mal para quemede este error alguien me puede ayudar.

> Cita en bloque  SQL Error: near ",": syntax error

```
UPDATE `users`,`score` SET `user`='usernew', `us_score`='usernew' WHERE `user` like 'userold' and `us_score` like 'userold'
```

Comment: UPDATE `users` SET `user`='usernew', `us_score`='usernew' WHERE `user` like 'userold' and `us_score` like 'userold'`  es posible que el error se deba a la palabra `score` después de `user`. Imagino que la tabla a actualizar es `users`. Para más detalles, [puedes ver](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-update/)

Comment: si ya busque y si es eso es que sql no suporta múltiples consultas T_T una pena

Comment: ¿Por qué no escribes dos `UPDATE`  separados: ***Primero:*** **`UPDATE users SET user='usernew' WHERE user like 'userold';`** ***Segundo:*** **`UPDATE score SET  us_score='usernew' WHERE  us_score like 'userold';`** Aunque dices que funciona en Mysql, no creo que funcione como lo tienes ahora, podrías hacerlo funcionar uniendo las tablas mediante `JOIN` usando las columnas relacionadas.